# How can this function be optimised?

Tags: r

The following takes about 20 minutes to complete on a 2.8 GHz 8-Core Macbook Pro with 32GB RAM. I am iterating through 2,800 rows where one column has a cell which contains a dataframe, each dataframe consisting of 8 columns and 10-30 observations each.

I attempted to optimise the process by using the apply functional to iterate over the dataframe. The score function is to be used iterating over dataframe rows, which I use with apply.

Does it take such a long time because it works with nested dataframes?

Each instance of row$prod, saved to the variable *prod.data* in the function, is itself a dataframe. One other columns in the dataframe is relevant to the processing in this function e.g row$stimuli.pitch[[1]], but there are about 40 other columns. Is this bound to be very slow?

```
score <- function(row) {

  # grab the stimuli the user heard
  pitch_vec1 <- str.mel.to.vector(row$stimuli.pitch[[1]], "-")
  dur_vec1 <- produce.arrhythmic.durs(pitch_vec1)
  
  prod.data <- row$prod
  
  if (any(!is.na(prod.data['pitch']))) {
    pitch_vec2 <- as.vector(unlist(prod.data['pitch']))
    dur_vec2 <- as.vector(unlist(prod.data['dur']))
    
  }
  else {
    pitch_vec2 <- NA
  }
  
  if(length(pitch_vec2) < 3 | length(pitch_vec1) < 3) { # skip if there is not enough pitches 
    score <- NA
  }
  
  else {
    score <- score_alg(pitch_vec1, dur_vec1, pitch_vec2, dur_vec2)
  }
  score

}

#  compute scores
scores <- apply(dat, MARGIN = 1, score)
```

Comment: Please tell me why the downvotes, so I can learn about how to ask better questions..

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this reads a little bit like "please fix my code for me". What have you thought about/tried in the way of optimization? Have you profiled your code? Can you give a [mcve]?  What does "a very long time" mean (what size data set, what hardware)?  What are all of the functions you refer to? Maybe they're just slow?

Comment: The code isn't broken, I am just trying to learn how to improve. Using a functional was an attempt to optimise it from what it was before. No, I have never profiled code before. 
I can come back with a minimal reproducible example, but my question was to do with whether my code shows any structural logic that is faulty and my cause the slowness. If not, then yes I can investigate the individual functions.

Comment: There's a separate side dedicated to [codereview.se]. Unless there's a more specific programming question, it's not really appropriate for Stack Overflow. "Doe this look fine"? really isn't a precise question. At the very least include data to run the code otherwise we have to run it in our head and that's even slower than what R can do.

Comment: Is it precise enough now? I am not really sure how I can provide that volume of data to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that you're not making any obvious errors here (e.g. growing data structures rather than pre-allocating them, failing to vectorize stuff that could obviously be vectorized ... I'd recommend [this presentation](https://www.noamross.net/archives/2013-04-25-faster-talk/) as a starting point (or the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/) for an older school approach).

The most obvious possibility is that one or more of the functions you're calling (`str.mel.to.vector`, `produce.arrhythmic.durs`, etc.) is just slow. You can either (1) *profile* your code to see which parts are slow (e.g. the [profvis package](https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/)) or (2) benchmark these functions individually and see whether the total time your function is taking is much longer than the expected time taken to repeat this sequence of operations for each row (e.g. using the  `rbenchmark` or `microbenchmark` packages).

There are small things (e.g. you might not need `as.vector()` in addition to `unlist()`? You might be able to speed things up by making objects matrices instead of data frames where possible?) but it's really not worth trying to optimize them before you find out whether it just takes this long to analyze 2800 rows ...